# error releasing grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm trying to release a new version of one of my plugins by running

```
grails publish-plugin
```

but I'm getting a 401 error. This seems to be because I'm using the [wrong username and password](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/401-when-deploying-to-Grails-central-repo-td4570924.html). However, I can't find any way to specify my username and password when running this command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define it at `~/.grails/settings.groovy`:

```
grails.project.repos.grailsCentral.username="..."
grails.project.repos.grailsCentral.password="..."
grails.release.scm.enabled=false
```

Comment: Also make sure it is your grails.org username and password.

Comment: Strange that it doesn't prompt you to enter your username and password on the command-line if they're not present in this file